# can you access a file from a virtual machine using locust.io and perform load testing on this file

Tags: python, locust

I am using locust.io for the first time. I want to access a file from a virtual machine which i have created using a get request in locust.io. I want to then simulate multiple users for this request. Is this possible using locust.io?

Basically the code below is what I want to replicate using locust.io for multiple users.
This is my code for a single client and server using sockets.

```
#server.py
import socket

port = 3335
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#host = socket.gethostname()
s.bind(('',port))
s.listen(5)

print("server Ready")

while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    print("connection received from ",addr)
    data = conn.recv(2048)
    #print("server received",repr(data))
    filename=data.decode()
    f=open(filename,'rb')
    l=f.read(1024)
    while(l):
        conn.send(l)
        print('sent',repr(l))
        l=f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print('done sending')
    #conn.send('thankyou'.encode())
    conn.close()


#client.py
import socket

port = 3335
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = input("Enter the ip address of server")
s.connect((host,port))
file = input("Enter the filename")
s.send(file.encode())

while True:
    print("receiving data")
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print("data = ",(data))
    if not data:
        break
print("successful")
s.close()
print("connection closed")
```

Comment: from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task class MyTaskSet(TaskSet): @task def my_task(self): self.client.get("/first.txt") class MyLocust(HttpLocust): task_set = MyTaskSet How should i specify the ip address of the ubuntu virtual machine which i am using as a server? i want to retrieve first.txt from that machine but am not able to.i tried locust -f locust_file.py --host =ip.of.my.machine but this gives a http connection error –

Comment: this question has nothing to do with Locust

Comment: Is it possible to send a get request to a different virtual machine using only it's ip address in locust?